# Kubernetes HPA doesn't scale down after decreasing the loads

Tags: kubernetes, hpa

the Kubernetes HPA works correctly when load of the pod increased but after the load decreased, the scale of deployment doesn't change. This is my HPA file:

```
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2beta2
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: baseinformationmanagement
  namespace: default
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: baseinformationmanagement
  minReplicas: 1
  maxReplicas: 3
  metrics:
  - type: Resource
    resource:
      name: cpu
      target:
        type: Utilization
        averageUtilization: 80
  - type: Resource
    resource:
      name: memory
      target:
        type: Utilization
        averageUtilization: 80
```

My kubernetes version:

```
> kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"16", GitVersion:"v1.16.1", GitCommit:"d647ddbd755faf07169599a625faf302ffc34458", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-10-02T17:01:15Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.10", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"17", GitVersion:"v1.17.2", GitCommit:"59603c6e503c87169aea6106f57b9f242f64df89", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-01-18T23:22:30Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

And this is my HPA describe:

```
> kubectl describe hpa baseinformationmanagement
Name:                                                     baseinformationmanagement
Namespace:                                                default
Labels:                                                   <none>
Annotations:                                              kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:
                                                            {"apiVersion":"autoscaling/v2beta2","kind":"HorizontalPodAutoscaler","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"baseinformationmanagement","name...
CreationTimestamp:                                        Sun, 27 Sep 2020 06:09:07 +0000
Reference:                                                Deployment/baseinformationmanagement
Metrics:                                                  ( current / target )
  resource memory on pods  (as a percentage of request):  49% (1337899008) / 70%
  resource cpu on pods  (as a percentage of request):     2% (13m) / 50%
Min replicas:                                             1
Max replicas:                                             3
Deployment pods:                                          2 current / 2 desired
Conditions:
  Type            Status  Reason              Message
  ----            ------  ------              -------
  AbleToScale     True    ReadyForNewScale    recommended size matches current size
  ScalingActive   True    ValidMetricFound    the HPA was able to successfully calculate a replica count from memory resource utilization (percentage of request)
  ScalingLimited  False   DesiredWithinRange  the desired count is within the acceptable range
Events:           <none>
```

Comment: maybe https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/ this could help you, Iikely if u can upgrade to 1.18

Comment: How long did you wait?  HPA intentionally is a little conservative in scaling down; when I've experimented with it in the past it can take 5+ minutes before it starts terminating pods.

Comment: Could you show the output of `$ kubectl describe hpa bankchannel`? Do you observe values there that should scale down the deployment?

Comment: @DavidMaze About 23 hours

Comment: @DawidKruk I added it to my question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your HPA specifies both memory and CPU targets.  The [Horizontal Pod Autoscaler](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/#algorithm-details) documentation notes:

> If multiple metrics are specified in a HorizontalPodAutoscaler, this calculation is done for each metric, and then the largest of the desired replica counts is chosen.

The actual replica target is a function of the current replica count and the current and target utilization (same link):

```
desiredReplicas = ceil[currentReplicas * ( currentMetricValue / desiredMetricValue )]
```

For memory in particular: `currentReplicas` is 2; `currentMetricValue` is 49; `desiredMetricValue` is 80.  So the target replica count is

```
desiredReplicas = ceil[       2        * (         49        /         80         )]
desiredReplicas = ceil[       2        *                   0.61                    ]
desiredReplicas = ceil[                          1.26                              ]
desiredReplicas = 2
```

Even if your service is totally idle, this will cause there to be (at least) 2 replicas, unless the service chooses to release memory back to the OS; that's usually up to the language runtime and a little out of your control.

Just removing the memory target and autoscaling based only on CPU might match better what you expect.

Comment: Thank you it was very useful for me. Can I separate memory and CPU HPA per deployment?

Comment: I don't think it makes sense to have two different autoscalers targeting the same deployment, if that's your question.